# Why do events come in out of order in DHIS2?

Tags: dhis2

I am experiencing some odd behavior with DHIS2. When capturing data on tracker capture, the events come in different orders.  For example, admission comes before treatment, but when I schedule another event, (lets say unscheduled visit) it comes before admission.

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Events in tracker capture are displayed in a sorted manner. They are sorted using eventDate (or dueDate if the event is under schedule).